# Take first line on website with JSOUP?

Tags: android, string, jsoup, fetch

I'm building an Android application who will fetch some Text from Website and put it in `TextView`.

Now I'm stuck on this part, where the app should fetch the string. This problem is specific because the string who I'm trying to fetch is not in any kind of tag.

Here is an example of web page source code.

```html
Example of;an string
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
//Some code
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to get that first line, `Example of;an string`, and put it in `TextView` in android.

Comment: Can you add a more concrete example? In the above example you have two possible strings: `Some title` or `//Some code`

Comment: No... You didn't read it...
I need this part
`"Example of;an string"`

Comment: Can you show me a site that looks like that? I have an idea and I want to try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line is not a valid part of the HTML, but it is a part of the HTTP response body, so it should be accessible like this:

```
Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).execute();
String[] bodyLines = response.body().split("\n");
String firstLine = bodyLines[0];
```

Comment: It won't work if the string is splitted across multiple lines.

Comment: It is in one line only.

Comment: It that case you would parse the body in a different way, for example using a regex. That would depend on its actual contents.

Comment: Okay this lines:
`String[] bodyLines = response.body().split("\n");
String firstLine = bodyLines[0];`
I get, and they are very helpful.
But this has to be done in background i think. Besides that, I need it in `TextView` with id textview1.
Could you help a little bit more, this is great for now.